# How to add hyperlink in ng2-smart-table in angular6

Tags: angular

[image]

Want to add hyper link in request id column. Can you please help how to add? 
I am using Ng2-smart-table with Angular6

Comment: This issue is still open ?

Comment: Yes @SachinShah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that in simple way like this.

Let's assume you have called API and got data like this.

```
data = [
   {
      fname:'sachin',
      lname:'shah'
   },
   {
      fname:'banty',
      lname:'shah'
   }
]
```

When you got this data you have to use `for loop`. And you have to update your table settings.

```
import { LocalDataSource } from 'ng2-smart-table';

source: LocalDataSource; // Add this above constructor 

// Update settings like this.. 

columns: {        
    user: {
      title: 'Name' ,
      type: 'html'      //  <---- hear you have to pass html as a type... 
    },

var temp : any =  [];
  for(let i = 0 ; i < res.data.length ; i++){
    var obj = {
      name:'<a href="'+res.data[i].fname+'">Link</a>',          
      ... ... ...
    }
    temp.push(obj);        
  }      
  this.source = new LocalDataSource(temp);
```

Hear I have attached my working code's screen shot.
[image: Link works in column]

Comment: Thanks a lot Sachin Shan.It's very usefull for me.

Comment: Have one more issue with the ng2-smartable. Can we have fixed header using the ng2-smart-table. (Header is fixed , while scroll down header part is unchange and rows moves up) How to resolve ?

Comment: i have added new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52916905/can-we-have-fixed-header-using-the-ng2-smart-table-in-angular-6

Comment: I am unable to upvote your answer due to less reputation. do you know any other way .Done and upvoted Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide solution for fixed header issue ?@Sachin