# Can we have fixed header using the ng2-smart-table in Angular 6

Tags: angular6

Header is fixed i.e staic one, while scroll down header part is unchange and rows moves up How to resolve ?

[image]

Comment: You mean use the ng-deep for the thead in css .
/deep/ ng2-smart-table table > thead {
    border: 0.5px solid;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
  } /deep/ ng2-smart-table table > thead > tr > th {
    border: 0.5px solid;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
   
  }

Comment: I have tried for that , but that is not working .. After apply css , header is fixed and first row is overlaps with header while scroll up  @ Sachin

Comment: It happens when you fixed header. Can you please add index or id value for a now. So I can view properly.

Comment: How to add index or id value for table header .
/deep/ ng2-smart-table table > thead {
    border: 0.5px solid;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
    position:fixed;
  }

  /deep/ ng2-smart-table table > thead > tr:first-child { 
    border: 0.5px solid;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
    position:fixed;
  }

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
:host ::ng-deep ng2-smart-table > table {
    table {
        width: 100%;
    }

    thead {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
    }

    thead, th {
        background-color: white;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    tbody {
        z-index: 0;
    }
}
```

The key here is the `position: sticky`.